# QTabWidget with dynamic change widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I'm using QTabWidget (pHTab composed in AbstractManagerTab) to show some data 
(IpTrafficPage and SpecTrafficPage widgets), 
and I need to dynamically add QPushButtons to added tabs.

When I start application, added buttons are visible only at the last tab.
What could be wrong?

```
class AbstractTrafficPage : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AbstractTrafficPage(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void addCommandButton(QWidget *btn);
private:
    QVBoxLayout *commBtnsLayout;
};

AbstractTrafficPage::AbstractTrafficPage(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    commBtnsLayout(new QVBoxLayout)
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(commBtnsLayout);
    mainLayout->addStretch();

    setLayout(mainLayout);
}

void AbstractTrafficPage::addCommandButton(QWidget *btn)
{
    commBtnsLayout->addWidget(btn);
}

class IpTrafficPage : public AbstractTrafficPage
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit IpTrafficPage(QWidget *parent = 0) : AbstractTrafficPage(parent) {};
};

class SpecTrafficPage : public AbstractTrafficPage
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SpecTrafficPage(QWidget *parent = 0) : AbstractTrafficPage(parent) {};
};

class AbstractManagerTab : public QWidget {
public:
    AbstractManagerTab(QWidget *parent);
    ~AbstractManagerTab();
    void addCommandButton(QWidget *btn);
private:
    QTabWidget *pHTab;
}

AbstractManagerTab::AbstractManagerTab(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
pHTab(new QTabWidget)
{
    IpTrafficPage *ipPage = new IpTrafficPage(this);
    pHTab->addTab(ipPage, tr("IP);
    SpecTrafficPage *specPage = new SpecTrafficPage(this);
    pHTab->addTab(specPage, tr("Spec"));

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(pHTab);
    setLayout(mainLayout);
}

AbstractManagerTab::~AbstractManagerTab()
{
    delete pHTab;
}

AbstractManagerTab::addCommandButton(QWidget *btn) 
{
    for (int index = 0; index < pHTab->count(); ++index) {
        AbstractTrafficPage *page = dynamic_cast<AbstractTrafficPage *>
                (pHTab->widget(index));
        if (page)
            page->addCommandButton(btn);
    }
}

class StoredRecsTab : public AbstractManagerTab
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit StoredRecsTab(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

StoredRecsTab::StoredRecsTab(QWidget *parent) :
    AbstractManagerTab(parent)
{
    QPushButton *createRecBtn = new QPushButton(tr("Create"), this);
    QPushButton *removeRecBtn = new QPushButton(tr("Remove"), this);

    addCommandButton(createRecBtn);
    addCommandButton(removeRecBtn);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any QWidget can have only one parent. If you want to add a button to many widgets, you need to create many button objects (one per tab).

Another option is to move the button to the visible tab on tab change. But I think it's not so good decision.

Comment: +1 For suggesting the other option that made me laugh :-P Indeed, I would not recommend it...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have to rethink the architecture.